# AngularJS controller reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, controller, ionic-framework

I'm running a AngularJS webapplication with ionic.

I got a headpage where I see a list of articles. When I click on this you'll get a seperate page with tabs.
When i go from the headpage to a tab-page the controller loads for the first time.

```
$scope.selectArt = function(artikel) {
  api.setCurrItem(artikel.artnr);
  $state.go('tab.voorraad');
}
```

The controller is will be loaded.

```
app.controller('ArtikelsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $location, api, artikels) {
    console.log("loaded");
};
```

I have a backbutton where I can go back to the headpage.
When I click on a item the selectArt function will be loaded again but the 'ArtikelsCrtl' will not be loaded again.

App.js

```
$stateProvider
.state('artikels', {
  url: '/artikels',
  templateUrl: 'app/artikels/artikels.html',
  controller: 'ArtikelsCtrl'
})

.state('tab', {
  url: '/tab',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'app/_shared/tabs.html'
})

.state('tab.voorraad', {
  url: '/voorraad',
  views: {
    'tab-voorraad': {
      templateUrl: 'app/voorraad/voorraad.html',
      controller: 'VoorraadCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Anyone got an idea why the controller don't load on the 2nd time?
It looks like the page just hide and show up again on $state.go.

Answer (score 1):

Controllers are initialised once per view. When you pass the controller option you are specifying how it is constructed. Changing view leaves the controller in existence.

Answer (score 1):

[`ui.router.state.$state`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

`$state.go(to, params, {reload : true})`

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Changed to this but not working.

`$state.go('tab.voorraad', {}, {reload : true});`